# FB.getLoginStatus() called before calling FB.init() error in console

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am trying to check if a user is logged in with my app, but I am getting a

> FB.getLoginStatus() called before calling FB.init().

error in the console. The `setSize` appears to work (although not entirely 1,710 height but definitely around 1,500) so I cannot understand why the `getLoginStatus()` gives the error.

I also double checked with the appID (removed below) and that is definitely correct. The script is included via `<script src="file.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` right below my `<body>` and `<div id="fb-root"></div>` div.

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
    appId      : 'APPID', // App ID
    status     : true, // check login status
    cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    oauth      : true, // enable OAuth 2.0
    xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML 
});

FB.Canvas.setSize({width: 520, height: 1710});

FB.Canvas.setAutoResize(100);

FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
        // logged in and connected user, someone you know
        alert("?");
    } else {
        // no user session available, someone you dont know
        alert("asd");
    }
});
};
```

Comment: where are you loading the api?

Comment: in the head as: <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to load the api asynchronously. Try removing your `<script src="connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>` and updating your JS to:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID', // App ID
      channelURL : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      oauth      : true, // enable OAuth 2.0
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    //
    // All your canvas and getLogin stuff here
    //
  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
   }(document));
</script>
```

Oh and check the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/)!

Comment: Can I mix this code with my jQuery code? I have a script include a jquery script i am running. Can I add this code to that or MUST it be below the fb-root div in the body?

Comment: Try it and see. I can't think of a reason it wouldn't work, so long as your fb processes are running in the correct order

Comment: jQuery can load js files too: `$.getScript(document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js');`

Comment: My problem is that i never intended to make FB app and i still get that error. i don't have any app id so that i can apply what you suggested :(

Answer (score 27):

This error will also occur if you don't provide an appId to FB.init. Example:

```
    FB.init({
        appId: ''
        , channelUrl: '//domain/channel.html'
        , status: true
        , cookie: true
    });
```

Will result in:

> FB.getLoginStatus() called before calling FB.init().

Comment: Thanks for adding this. I had already made the asynchronous change but was still getting the error.

Comment: I had the same issue with a misleading error message. This answer helped.