# HTML / CSS height fix for Blogger based website using the Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, blogger, blogspot

I've problems on my website, and I'm a not very experienced HTML / CSS coder, I'd like of any help about my height problem on Internet Explorer. Chrome, Opera and Firefox it never occurs.

Here's my website:

http://www.joshcellsoftwares.com/

I've detected an unique problem that occurs on the Internet Explorer when the CSS loads, is the Height bug.

Sometimes the website height abnormally scroll down, and the size isn't correctly rendered as this picture:

[image]

I hope to solve it with any JavaScript or HTML that can fix the height on this browser.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I wouldn't bother trying to debug invalid HTML: [Your validation results:](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.joshcellsoftwares.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) `132 Errors, 9 warning(s)` While no browser is fond of invalid source code, some handle it differently than others.

Comment: I've fixed so much all these errors.

But the page still have 8 Errors and 6 warnings. Anyone can help-me on fixing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting all that extra space as you have a JS error that prevents the page from fully loading. If you use the developer tool in IE (F12), you'll see that your `body` still has the class `loading` when the page loads correctly (no extra space), the final bit of JS fired and the `body` doesn't have that class any more. So it dies before that point.

The only error showing up on console and using breakpoints in the IE developer tool (F12) is: `FB.getLoginStatus() called before calling FB.init()`. This is coming from your `2000000996-widgets.js`.

The solution to properly initializing FB is addressed in another post, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8048564/fb-getloginstatus-called-before-calling-fb-init-error-in-console).

Comment: I've added an async script loading at the end of the header, and are looking good at the moment..

What are you think?

Comment: I switched machines and don't have a native IE near me at the moment, but if it looks good to you, then that change fixed it. I am still getting the FB error on console (even on Chrome) when going to the site, so I don't know if you fixed this on a dev site or the live one or if the change you made fixed what you were originally talking about and this is now a separate issue.

Comment: Right, I've hard worked and fixed this error, and my validation results is showing 8 Errors and 6 warning(s) still...

The Internet Explorer problem looks that was solved with it, but anyone can help me fixing the W3C validation errors? Here's the link:

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.joshcellsoftwares.com/&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: You should probably take up one issue per question. If your issue you started with is handled, then you should end off on this question. If you have another then you should post that question. Nobody will see a question about getting validation assistance on this question when its subject is already solved. Also covered in the FAQ (http://stackoverflow.com/faq)