# web plugin like box browser issues

Tags: facebook, iframe, facebook-social-plugins

On my website, I am able to see the plugin in Chrome while others cannot. No one is able to see the plugin in IE. I tried using the iframe code and now I am using the HTML5 code. Any ideas?

http://craftcaferochester.com/

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This is probably your problem:

```
FB.getLoginStatus() called before calling FB.init().
```

I saw it in Chrome console. To resolve, see this:

[`FB.getLoginStatus() called before calling FB.init() error in console`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8048564/1693859)

**Update:**

You should register at [Facebook Developers](https://developers.facebook.com) to obtain the `appId` and `channelUrl`. Go to [JavaScript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) and read the `Loading and Initialization` section. When you registered as a developer, you may obtain them from [App Dashboard](https://developers.facebook.com/apps).

Comment: I am not sure where I find my appId and channelURL. Do I need these?

Comment: @user2257875, Of course. You do need them in order to integrate Facebook with your website. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I was able to solve my own problem. In the business settings, I had a country restriction on, restricting my page just to the USA. I turned off all restrictions and it seems to work fine now. Strange.