# FACEBOOK Like button does not display <div class="fb-like"...>

Tags: html, css, facebook

My buttons were there yesterday, but today they are gone.  I've tried moving the div all around the page with no luck.  Tried giving it a background-color and forcing a width and height.  This did cause the div to display on load but only to resize to zero.  It is in a nested div like this

```
<div id="top"  
    style="
    background-image:url('images/sante_nutrition33.png');
    background-size:415px 75px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:30px 0px;
    height:105px">
<div style="float:right; padding:50px 50px; 0px 0px; font:15px arial,sans-serif; font-weight:bold; color:rgb(96,57,139); overflow:visible;">Isabelle Gaetz, RHN

<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://santenut.ca/main.php?page=services&amp;lang=en" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false" data-send="true"></div>

</div></div>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Does the facebook-connect JS code load correctly? Can you see it in the "Developer Tools" (if using chrome, or any similar tool for other browsers)

Comment: ok Ofir, not entirely sure what you are asking.  I can say it worked yesterday and I use similar code on another website.  Not sure how to check if it loads correctly.

Comment: Do you have `fb-like`set with a background image in css somewhere? There's no image in the div.

Comment: I have this warning: FB.getLoginStatus() called before calling FB.init().

Comment: Patrick, I am using the code straight from the FB developer site.  I don't have any styling applied to "fb-like"

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8048564/fb-getloginstatus-called-before-calling-fb-init-error-in-console

Comment: Somewhat Resolved... I turns out that there was nothing wrong with my code.  Somehow Facebook suddenly refused to acknowledge my url.  I changed the link and VOILA the buttons came back?!?!? As a consequence I've lost all my likes.  Very Strange indeed.